# Как вызвать функцию при выборе текста в Text() в tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

Хочу сделать свой текстовый редактор и столкнулся с вопросом, на который не могу найти ответ. У меня есть текстовое поле, Spinbox, который содержит в себе шрифт для текста.

```
# Textarea creation.
textarea = Text(middle_frame,
                bg=textarea_color,
                fg=text_color,
                font=(chosen_font.get(), chosen_font_size.get()),
                yscrollcommand=textarea_scrollbar.set,
                highlightthickness=0,
                bd=0)
textarea.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

# Creating select box for fonts.
font_select = ttk.Combobox(tool_frame, textvariable=chosen_font)
font_select.grid(row=0, column=0)
font_select['values'] = ['Times New Roman'] + list(font.families())
font_select['state'] = 'readonly'

# Creating spinbox for font size.
font_size_spinbox = Spinbox(tool_frame,
                            from_=0,
                            to=100,
                            textvariable=chosen_font_size,
                            width=3)
font_size_spinbox.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мне нужно при выделении текста вызывать функцию, чтобы в Spinbox записать значение шрифта для выделенного текста, а также название самого шрифта, как мне это сделать?